# Angular component with custom validation

Tags: css, angular, validation, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular 5 component that is basically just a label and input

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="wwid">WWID</label>
    <input id="wwid" required ...lots of attrs...>
</div>
```

Using CSS I've then defined a style:

```
.ng-invalid:not(form) {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

When the field is blank, I'm getting two red borders.  The one on the input field that I want, but also one to the right of the label that I do not want.  How do I get rid of the red line on the label?

[image]

Here's the actual full HTML that used by the component.

```
<ng-template #listSelectionFormatter let-r="result">
    <span>{{r.wwid}} - {{r.fullName}}</span>
</ng-template>

<div class="form-group">
    <label *ngIf="labelText" for="wwid">
        {{ labelText }}
        <span *ngIf="isRequired">&nbsp;<sup class="requiredIndicator">*</sup></span>
    </label>

    <!-- inputFormatter is the format for what is placed into the input field after choosing from the dropdown -->
    <input id="wwid" type="text"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Search by WWID, IDSID, Name or Email"
           (selectItem)="onWorkerSelected($event.item)"
           (input)="onTextFieldChanged($event.target.value)"
           [ngModel]="selectedWorker"
           [ngbTypeahead]="search"
           [inputFormatter]="selectedResultsFormatter"
           [resultTemplate]="listSelectionFormatter"
           [disabled]="disabled"
           [required]="required"
    />
    <span *ngIf="searching">searching&hellip;</span>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">Lookup failed.</div>
</div>
```

The `requiredIndicator` thing is just for an older style I was using to show an asterisk if it was required, and used this CSS:

```
.requiredIndicator {
  color: red;
  font-size: larger;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.1em;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Why is the label "Closed By" on the screenshot and "WWID" on the posted code? There's nothing between the label and input?

Comment: I just posted a minimal HTML example.  I'll go update the question with the full HTML

Comment: I've tested it on "vanilla" angular (no bootstrap) and don't have any issue. Could you make a StackBlitz? Or easier first, try to inspect that border with your browser and see where it's coming from. There must be something with a `ng-invalid` class in that area, for some reason.

Comment: Trying...It won't show the bar at all there for the subcomponent.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7zssyd

Comment: You're missing a `ngModel` attr on that input I think, referring to `selectedWorker`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182536/discussion-between-gargoyle-and-jeto).